# Service MSFTESQL not found

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, dynamics-crm

While  installating MS-CRM:I got sql server errors:-
1>Service MSFTESQL not found. The specified service does not exists as an installed service
-----but i can see the service is running automatically and help file says

```
**"verify that you have local administrator permissions for the computer on which  sql server is running. And if necessary grant the needed permissions."
```

how to achive this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have downloaded the setup updates and see also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957053.

You will find the required permissions in detail here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946677